# Subclassing content type forms

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I was wondering how would you guys approach a situation where your Drupal7 site required a couple of custom content type, yet most of the fields would be shared across them. What I mean resembles a typical object-oriented case of a super class and its subclasses.

I want it so that I can make the admin-side content filling easier for the owner of the site. I also assume that for me, as the author of the form it would be a great time-saver if I could base one on another.

Is it possible? Does it make sense? Or would you rather make one type with all possible fields merged onto one form, then tweak the suggestion template so that irrelevant parts are /shown/hidden upon changing a dropdown menu that specifies the subclass?

Anyone been through a similar problem?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Give a look here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27741/inheriting-fields-from-a-base-content-type

Answer (score 1):

> Or would you rather make one type with all possible fields merged onto
>   one form, then tweak the suggestion template so that irrelevant parts
>   are /shown/hidden upon changing a dropdown menu that specifies the
>   subclass?

If you're going the single-type route, here are two tips: Drupal Forms API supports conditions, check the [docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7); it might be useful to take a look at the [Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module.

Comment: Prepopulate and conditions don't really answer data structure inheritance. Not quite a -1 because you could hack your way into mimicking some of the goal.

Comment: Did I make myself clearer now? It's not about data inheritance between the different content types, it's about using a single content-type and hiding fields. Of course, it will also need some #validation handlers to ignore unused field values. And maybe Display Suite to handle different node views.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to use actual object-oriented inheritance. However, you can manage the field configurations in such a way that you attach them to multiple content types based on some flag--typically a content type-specific variable.

Using the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module's Field export hooks (namely, `hook_field_default_fields()` and `hook_field_default_fields_alter()`), you can programmatically define fields for multiple types. In fact, once [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1064472) lands, you can have a central definition for a field, then separate instance definitions to attach and configure that field for each content type.

For form changes in general, you could capture multiple node types in the same [form alter logic](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to create common tweaks to certain nodes. In both cases, you might end up using code such as

```
if (variable_get($node->type . '_is_a_shape', FALSE)) {
  // Apply changes to form/data structure.
}
```