# Is inheritance between content types possible?

Tags: entities

I just read [Should I use a seperate content type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29413/should-i-use-a-seperate-content-type), and it's got me thinking.

Say I had a site with twenty-five content types, with some of the content types sharing enough of the features of some of the other content types to make some kind of "inheritance" worthwhile: I'm thinking in terms of object-oriented PHP here. Is content type inheritance possible in Drupal 6? Is it possible in Drupal 7? Or 8? Could a module be written to make it possible?

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/bundle_inherit :)

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27741/inheriting-fields-from-a-base-content-type

Comment: I can't answer my own question for another 7 hours, apparently / Thanks for the link, very useful :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Drupal 7 there's the [Bundle Inherit](http://drupal.org/project/bundle_inherit) module.

Comment: Thanks! This was pretty easy...I wrote a few more details here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11645/how-to-copy-content-type-in-drupal-7/75421#75421

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module which is exactly what it sounds like, the ability for one node to reference another node for which you can easily retrieve the information of the referenced node/user/etc. through Views or the PHP API. This is very similar to using taxonomies except they are treated as a node would generally be treated.

You can set up automatic back references with a module or simply do a back reference through views computationally upon request.

edit: This references system is less like inheritance and more like composition which is generally the preferred method in object orientation computer science theory.