# Inherit some fields from referenced Nodes?

Tags: nodes, entities

I need to link one content type to another via inheriting certain fields, similar to the question about "[inheriting fields from a base content type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27741/inheriting-fields-from-a-base-content-type)", but automated.

I have a content type called 'Session', under which you can assign 'Classes' via Node Reference. A Session will have a Time allocated, among other fields.

I want to be able to have my Classes inherit the **node-referenced Session's Time field, but not any of the others**. It must also automatically inherit any changes to the referenced Sessions' Time field.

I've already tried [Bundle Inherit](https://www.drupal.org/project/bundle_inherit), but in order to actually use Inheritance via Strict mode, this only allows inheriting ALL fields, not some. It also detects adding extra fields to the parent content type and adds them to the child.

Can anyone suggest a non-PHP way I might achieve this?

Comment: it could probably be done via Rules, on add new or save existing content of type Session - set a data value (in a loop for multiple) in related Classes. Might require some php, but I think it could be done just through the UI

Comment: Do you know if there's a non-PHP method? I should have mentioned that :)